# fill treeview with ado.net db connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, treeview

I am trying to add my datas from database to my treeview according to their 'Category' attribute. I have yangin,kamera,alarm and otomasyon categories and analog,HDCVI,HDTVI,AHD and IP as childnodes. For example I have two datas with "HDCVI Kameralar" value in Category attribute. I need these two datas to appear under the "HDCVI Kameralar" node.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Yangın" Value="Yangin"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Kamera" Value="Kamera">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Analog Kameralar" Value="Analog Kameralar"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="HDCVI Kameralar" Value="HDCVI Kameralar"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="HDTVI Kameralar" Value="HDTVI Kameralar"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="AHD Kameralar" Value="AHD Kameralar"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="IP Kameralar" Value="IP Kameralar"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Alarm" Value="Alarm"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Otomasyon" Value="Otomasyon"></asp:TreeNode>
            </Nodes>
        </asp:TreeView>
```

Examples in web were too complicated for me.I just don't know what to do in that foreach loop.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ here like this:-

```
private void CreateTreeView()
{
   //Don't filter the list 
   List<ProductTable> newSource = entity.ProductTable.ToList();
   foreach (var i in newSource)
   {
       //find the node with matching atribute 
       TreeNode node = TreeView1.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>()
                                          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == i.Attribute);
       //finally add new treenodes 
       if(node != null)
            node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode { Text = i.Attribute, Value = i.Category});
   }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i need. Thank you :)

Comment: By the way, if I need to add these datas to a child node, what should I do? I mean if a have 2 other categories in camera like IP camera and HDCVI cameras.I changed my database categories as hdcvi or ip camera.Thanks again. @Rahul Singh

Comment: @KorayDurudogan - You mean to say one more level down?

Comment: Yes :) sorry if my english is broken

Comment: @KorayDurudogan - Hey right now it must be displaying Camera and it's respective item as child node right? If you wanna go further down you can again do the same.

Comment: I tride same for hdcvi cameras but it turned an error like no node element found. It must just check nodes, not child nodes

Comment: @KorayDurudogan - I am confused now, can you edit your question and show some sample data? I will try to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: 'TreeNode cameraNode = TreeView1.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>()
                                                     .First(x => x.Text == "Kamera");
                TreeNode hdcvi = cameraNode.ChildNodes.OfType<TreeNode>().First(y => y.Text == i.UrunKategori);
                hdcvi.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode { Text = i.UrunAdi, Value = i.UrunId.ToString() });' This did the trick.Thank you very much I get the logic :)

Comment: @KorayDurudogan - Great :)